# Change file name when using window.location to download

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `window.location` to download my image. It isn't in `HTML` because I generate the image on the server and then send it back down so it looks like :

```
window.location = data.url;
```

I've seen a few other questions but they suggest the `download` attr which I don't have because there's no `HTML`.

Is there a way I can change the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Front-end solution

The only thing you can do on the front-end side is to change your code to HTML `<a>` element with `download` attribute:

```
<a href="my_file.pdf" download="very_important_report.pdf">Download</a>
```

When user clicks this link, the browser forces download and saves the file with given filename. You can read more about it in [this post](https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute). It's quite a new feature so check the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=download).

## Back-end solution

If you can modify the server-side code then you should use `content-disposition` header as defined in [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183).

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=very_important_report.pdf
```

Comment: Could I do something like `$("<a href="+"data.url"+" download="very_important_report.pdf"></a>").submit()` so I create the `HTML` and trigger it via with js?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. You can't effectively trigger a `click` on the link without user's interaction because of safety concerns.

Comment: @PourMeSomeCode was my answer helpful to you in any way?

Comment: yes, sorry about the long wait between accepting your answer. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

I've been wondering about it as well and saw this post but I was also using vuejs for the project and want the export to be continues even when switching from one page to another so I tried something and it did work here is another solution:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.setAttribute('href', '<yourlink_or_data>');
link.setAttribute('download', 'filename.ext');
link.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the filename on the client side. You would have to do that on the server.

You could set the content-disposition header (on the server side) like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourname.gif"
```